# Can I host my React/redux (client and api server) project on github pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server, github-pages

I know I can host my react/redux app on github pages by just serving the bundle.js and index.html, but can I also host an api server for the backend that is say username.github.io/api?

The server uses node.js/express and they are separate directories.

Also, can I make the server repository private and still host it on /api?

I looked through the documentation on github pages about creating "projects" but it doesn't make much since to me.

If anyone can shed some light on this, it would be must appreciated.

Comment: No. GitHub Pages is for static files, not servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you run your ***front-end*** code on ***github*** while having an externally hosted api on say, ***AWS*** or google cloud.

Amazon and google both provide free packages for small scale operations!

This way you can have your github page request data from ***AWS*** or google cloud!

Comment: Yeah I've tried with digital ocean, but they require both the servers to use https which gave me an issue :\ I guess ill have to get an ssl cert for my server app

Comment: You don't need to run ssl on AWS or google cloud! @nateph

Answer (score 3):

No. GitHub Pages are static. They're generated using a variation of [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), a templated flat site generator. As such, they're only flat HTML, CSS and Javascript.

You could host your frontend React application in them, but not server-side application code or a database.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to run any custom server code on Github pages, you can only host static files (HTML, images, front-end javascript etc).

Answer (score 2):

You could do that if you are able to convert your code to  static HTML + Resources (JS+CSS+IMAGES+FONTS..). 
To do that, it is recommended to use **webpack**

Once you finish coding, you build your project using :

```
NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.prod.js
```

This will generate static HTML + JS of your code .